# Rails fallback database on initialize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

Our Rails setup includes two databases, I wrote a solution to dynamically switch between the two if Rails *is already running* and one db goes down. Now the problem is, Rails can't boot if the default environment database is down, and I have a requirement to make it so.

1. Is it a good idea to hack into the Rails initialization to make it aware of the dual database setup ?
2. Where exactly can I do this ? I can't use any of the ActiveRecord methods to test the database before application.rb where we 'require' it, but at the same time, if the database is down the require fails immediately on startup.

Here's my database.yml

`development:

  adapter: oracle_enhanced

  database: xxxx:1521/SID

  username: user

  password: pass

  failover: development_secondary

  pool: 30

  timeout: 45000`

development_secondary:
  adapter: oracle_enhanced
  database: xxxx:1521/SID
  username: user
  password: pass
  pool: 30
  timeout: 45000

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an app problem, I don't recommend doing this in Rails.  Use an external solution with non-cached DNS records.  Keep your application layer ignorant of the status of your database nodes.  Amazon, Rackspace and most other cloud providers offer DNS failover.

You can also consider using a gem like [Octopus](https://github.com/tchandy/octopus)